# Grub doesn't resume Windows 10 hibernation

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-10, hibernate

Recently i've received a Dell Inspiron 7501 laptop, and i've installed on it ubuntu 18.04 alongside the preinstalled windows 10. The issue is that windows hibernation works perfectly when the windows boot manager is selected as the first boot option (from the BIOS), but when the grub is used to start Windows no program is restored from the hibernation. Also, if i hibernate windows, then boot ubuntu through the grub and then boot windows from the Windows Boot Manager, the hibernation isn't resumed correctly: so i suppose that some code executed by the grub when choosing a boot option breaks something. From the windows event viewer i can see 2 events describing this error:

- Windows experienced an unexpected shutdown
- Windows could not resume from hibernation (error code 0xC0000004)

I've tried many fixes online (from bios updates to driver updates and so on) but nothing seems to work. One last detail, one friend of mine has the same laptop and installed ubuntu in the exact same way i did, but he doesn't have this issue. Just to be sure, i replaced ubuntu 18 with ubuntu 20 (wiping its partition), but it didn't change anything.

Comment: Check the seating of the memory SIM's..   Sounds like you have a memory corruption..   download and run MEMTEST86 and to confirm that your memory  good   .https://www.techpowerup.com/memtest64/

Comment: @SimonBanks it's been running for a while, but no error has been found (also, if it can help, i've launched yesterday the full dell diagnostic on startup, but no issue popped up)